# Automate maintenance of Authorized JavaScript origins for large number of domains

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

We are using the google drive sdk on a large number of domains to load the google picker. In order for this to work we need to manually enter all domains in the Authorized JavaScript Origins field of the Developer Console. Additionally, when we remove or change a domain we will have to go back in to the list and clean up.

Is there anyway to automate this process (via API, anything)? The number of domains that we need to maintain means that manual entry is a non-starter.